# How to replace email addresses with mailto links in a live web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Imagine this: you come across a webpage that says "Just send a message to user@example.com" but to actually send the email, you need to highlight the address and then cut and paste it into the recipient field of a new compose window of your email client of choice.

Obviously life would be easier if it were simply a mailto: link, so you could click on it and have a new message created automatically. How do I build an extension that turns email addresses into clickable mailto: links?

I was originally going to ask if there was an extension to enable similar functionality for unlinked Twitter @username mentions but I thought this email address problem would be a simpler situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Use `innerHTML` to replace the email</s> - **No**, this breaks page's, especially because event listeners are removed and attributes are also replaced.

Recursively loop through all nodes:

- **Loop in the reverse order**, to prevent conflicts when you modify the DOM.
- For each item, check it's [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType) value.

  - If `.nodeType === 1` (element), call the function again (recursion).
  - If `.nodeType === 3` (text node):

    1. Use a regular expression and the [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method to find *one* email address. Use the result's `.index` property to know the starting position of the email address, and `result[0].length` to know the length of the address.
    2. Use the node's [`splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Text.splitText) method cut the text node in three parts.
    3. Create an `<a>` element.
    4. Append the email's text node (the second text node from the previous) to this anchor. It's automatically removed from the document.
    5. Insert this link before the third node.

### Demo

Not a chrome extension, but it shows how a chrome extension would behave: http://jsfiddle.net/ckw89/

### Chrome extension

(the regexp is based on [MongoEngine's `EmailField` pattern](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/fields.py#L129)):

#### `script.js`

```
 // Initiate recursion
 wrapLink(document.body);

 function wrapLink(elem) { // elem must be an element node
     var nodes = elem.childNodes
       , i = nodes.length
       , regexp = /([-!\x23$%&'*+\/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+(\.[-!\x23$%&'*+\/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+)*|^"([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f!\x23-\\[\\]-\x7f]|\\[\x01-011\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}/i
       , node, emailNode, a, result;
     while (node = nodes[--i]) {
         if (node.nodeType === 1) {
             // Skip anchor tags, nested anchors make no sense
             if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'A')
                wrapLink(node);
         } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
             // 1: Please note that the regexp has NO global flag,
             //    and that `node.textContent` shrinks when an address is found
             while (result = regexp.exec(node.textContent)) {
                 // 2: Contact <SPLIT> me@example.com for details
                 node = node.splitText(result.index);

                 // 2: Contact <SPLIT>me@example.com<SPLIT> for details
                 node = node.splitText(result[0].length);

                 // me@example.com
                 emailNode = node.previousSibling

                 // 3. Create link
                 a = document.createElement('a');
                 a.href = 'mailto:' + result[0];

                 // 4: Append emailNode
                 a.appendChild(emailNode);

                 // 5: Insert before
                 elem.insertBefore(a, node);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

This script will work immediately when used as a [Content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), because its only interaction with the page is the DOM. For completeness, here's the contents of the [`manifest.json`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) file:

```
{
    "name": "Turns email addresses in `mailto:`s",
    "version": "1",
    "version_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }]
}
```

### Performance notice

The current script replaces all nodes in the live document. Consider moving the root node (eg `<body>`) to a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment) before manipulating.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for the amazing answer! I really appreciate your pseudocode explanation of how the script needs to loop through the DOM. Next step for me I suppose is to make the crx file and see about implementing the DocumentFragment approach.

Comment: What about for Firefox? :( I thought you work for Mozilla!! haha the question linking here was asking about both chrome and fx i thought :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440603/how-to-replace-a-piece-of-html-with-another-piece-of-html-on-a-page

Comment: @Noitidart As you can see from the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/ckw89/) in the center of my answer, the logic in my answer is browser-independent. It can be used in a Chrome extension, but also a Firefox addon (and any web page in general).

Comment: Ah thanks for that, Ill update tags so firefox devusers can benefit from this too :)

Comment: @RobW I need to ask your opinion, as the answerer, whether Noitidart's edit to the question is justified. If you think it's okay, I'll withdraw my opposition.