# Chrome extension action when cursor over email address

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a chrome extension that will fire when I move my cursor over an email address that is on the screen.  All the searches I do return results of existing extensions in the chrome store.  I would like to know which extension method and ideal see an example of how to capture the email address and send that as a parameter to a custom API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit broad, but a high-level overview would be:

1. Inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in all pages you want to monitor;
2. In a content script, identify all email addresses in the DOM
   (and possibly [monitor for new dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener));
3. Wrap addresses in `<span>` if required, add listeners to appropriate events (`"mouseover"`? `"mouseenter"`?);
4. Do what you want when the listener fires: [inform the main script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), inject some HTML as your UI in the page, [communicate with your API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), etc.

Comment: Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` for performance. For an efficient method of tackling (3), see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209628/is-there-a-chrome-extension-to-add-mailto-links-to-email-addresses

Comment: I know it is a bit broad, always a challenge to keep it out of the weeds of my specific situation.  Your high-level overview I think will point me in the right direction.  If I get a working sample I'll update with a link.