# How to replace a piece of HTML with another piece of HTML on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm making a simple browser extension which is supposed to be used for links addition on a page.
The extension should to find text occurrences with references to laws and wrap them in links to corresponding pages with texts of laws.

For example, the reference "`chapter 1 of Some Law`" in a text "`The topic covered in the chapter 1 of Some Law`" should be wrapped with link like this - "`The topic covered in <a href="http://link-to-the-law.text">chapter 1 of Some Law</a>`"

A user interacts with the extension this way:

1. selects some text on a page (it can include many DOM elements)
2. triggers text wrapping by clicking a right-click menu button
3. CORS with the selected text are performed to our server
4. a text with law references wrapped in links is returned
5. the selected text is replaced with the returned text

Now I've stuck with the step 5. I have a `Selection object` and a raw received HTML with wrapped references.

Is it possible (and how if so) to replace a selected text (which actually is a bunch of DOM elements) with a received text? 
May be you have encountered some extensions/libraries/etc which acts similarily? Or may be you know a better way to do such a replacement? If so please let me know.

Comment: The duplicate is for Chrome, what about for Firefox? :(

Comment: @Noitidart The other question asks about the logic for a Chrome extension, but the given answer is browser-independent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but from what I understand you want to replace DOM elements with other DOM elements. Look into [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) and/or [createElement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp).

Comment: Yes, set of DOM elements with HTML.  As I understand innerHTML just sets HTML into an element, but I need replace arbitrary set of DOM elements (which have been selected, some of them might be even not complete - e.g. if a user selected just a piece of a paragraph) .

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span just use <a> instead of <span>

Comment: The question is about wrapping selected text, but not about replacing it, thanks anyway.